# LINQ's SelectMany Equivalent in OData

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, odata

I have an entity called `AccountAction` that has property called `TransactionTypes` that is an `ICollection` of `TransactionType` entities.

I return a list of all the `TransactionTypes` that are related to all the `AccountActions` in a method called `GetTransactionTypes`. I would like to apply query options to the returned list of `TransactionTypes`. However, so far I have hit a wall because all of the query options are applied to `AccountActions`.

Is there any way I can apply query options in the URL to the returned lists of `TransactionTypes`? In other words, is there a way I can do a `SelectMany` from the URL to get the `TransactionTypes` related to the `AccountActions` to move on to apply the query options to the found `TransactionTypes`?

Below is an extract of the code that I am using.

```
[Route(FullControllerPath + "/TransactionTypes")]
public IHttpActionResult GetTransactionTypes(ODataQueryOptions<AccountAction> queryOptions, bool addCols, int? skip, int? take)
{
    using (AccountActionManagement _accountActionManage = new AccountActionManagement(this.GenerateInformation()))
    {
        _accountActionManage.SetTraslationList("DATASTRUCT-CONFIG-ACCOUNTACTIONTRANSACTIONTYPE", language);

        // Query composition
        IQueryable<TransactionType> query = queryOptions.ApplyTo(_accountActionManage.GetTypeAsQueryable<AccountAction>())
                                                        .OfType<AccountAction>()
                                                        .SelectMany(aa => aa.TransactionTypes)
                                                        .Include(tt => tt.AccountActionForDefaultTransactionType.DefaultTransactionType);

        var queryData = query.Select(tt => new
                        {
                            Id = tt.Id,
                            Name = tt.Name,
                            Operation = tt.Operation,
                            Type = tt.Type,
                            Default = tt.AccountActionForDefaultTransactionType != null && 
                                      tt.AccountActionForDefaultTransactionType.DefaultTransactionType.Id == tt.Id,
                            Version = tt.AccountActionForDefaultTransactionType.Version
                        });
        // Get count
        int totalRows = queryData.Count();

        // Get biggest version in query
        var maxVersion = queryData.Max(i => i.Version);

        // Get data from database
        var queryResult = queryOptions.OrderBy == null 
                              ? queryData.OrderBy(i => i.Id)
                                         .Skip(skip ?? 0)
                                         .Take(take ?? totalRows)
                                         .ToList() 
                              : queryData.Skip(skip ?? 0)
                                         .Take(take ?? totalRows)
                                         .ToList();
...}}
```

As seen in the diagram below, AccountAction has a many-to-many relationship to `TransactionType`. `AccountAction` has the first role and `TransactionType` has the second role.

[image: AccountActionTransactionTypeDiagram]

Comment: Your diagram says that the relationship between `AccountAction` and `TransactionTypes` is a One-To-Many rather than a Many-To-Many. Which is correct?

Comment: AccountAction and TransactionTypes are just mere tags. The fact that AccountAction is singular and TransactionTypes is plural does not indicate the nature of the relationship. Rather, the asterisks indicate the multiplicity of the relationship.

Comment: I deleted the tags next to the entities from the image as I saw they were misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this issue. I realized that I was not passing the right type to the `ApplyTo` method. Now, I apply the query options to an `IQueryable` of `TransactionType`s instead of applying the query options to an `IQueryable` of `AccountAction`s.

Below is the code with the described modification. Also, a diffchecker of the change I made is [here](https://www.diffchecker.com/bg5zmsnc).

```
[Route(FullControllerPath + "/TransactionTypes")]
public IHttpActionResult GetTransactionTypes(ODataQueryOptions<AccountAction> queryOptions, bool addCols, int? skip, int? take)
{
    using (AccountActionManagement _accountActionManage = new AccountActionManagement(this.GenerateInformation()))
    {
        _accountActionManage.SetTraslationList("DATASTRUCT-CONFIG-ACCOUNTACTIONTRANSACTIONTYPE", language);

        // Query composition
        IQueryable<TransactionType> query = queryOptions.ApplyTo(_accountActionManage.GetTypeAsQueryable<AccountAction()
                               .SelectMany(aa => aa.TransactionTypes)
                               .Include(aa =>      aa.AccountActionForDefaultTransactionType.DefaultTransactionType))
                               .OfType<TransactionType>();


        var queryData = query.Select(tt => new
                        {
                            Id = tt.Id,
                            Name = tt.Name,
                            Operation = tt.Operation,
                            Type = tt.Type,
                            Default = tt.AccountActionForDefaultTransactionType != null && 
                                      tt.AccountActionForDefaultTransactionType.DefaultTransactionType.Id == tt.Id,
                            Version = tt.AccountActionForDefaultTransactionType.Version
                        });
        // Get count
        int totalRows = queryData.Count();

        // Get biggest version in query
        var maxVersion = queryData.Max(i => i.Version);

        // Get data from database
        var queryResult = queryOptions.OrderBy == null 
                              ? queryData.OrderBy(i => i.Id)
                                         .Skip(skip ?? 0)
                                         .Take(take ?? totalRows)
                                         .ToList() 
                              : queryData.Skip(skip ?? 0)
                                         .Take(take ?? totalRows)
                                         .ToList();
...}}
```